# how can i create security catalog(.cat file)

Tags: file-extension

A catalog file contains a list of files and a digest of those files. A digest is a number generated by an algorithm to uniquely identify a given file, like a fingerprint. The digest is used for security/validation purposes.

what is usage of this file??
how can i create .cat file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.cat files are usually used to sign driver installation packages. Such a package usually contains multiple files (a minimum of .sys + .inf, often several others files), so instead of signing (and later validating) each file separately, the maker produces a .cat file which lists all the included files' names and hashes, and then signs only the .cat file (ideally through WHQL).

To create a .cat, you can use either:

- MakeCat.Exe (from Windows SDK)
- Signability (from WDK (Windows Driver Kit) [ref](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731458%28WS.10%29.aspx))
- Inf2Cat ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))